# Symfony crash after attack (failed opening required)

Tags: php, symfony, apache2

Almost every week on sunday morning (4am), I receive such error log lines in my debian6 server :

> [Sun Nov 23 04:10:05 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mydomain/www.myd\x81\x19\xa8k\xc4n\xf8\xf7H' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/mydomain/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2703
>
> GnuTLS: Handshake Failed (-8) 'A record packet with illegal version was received.'

After about 20 such entries, my website crash completly, and log displays on each visit:

> [client 157.55.39.25] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContextAwareInterface in /home/mydomain/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/RequestContextAwareInterface.php on line 17

It seems that a robot attack includes wrong data in Symfony cache, and the website is then no more able to handle further request.

I have no cron jobs at 4 am which could explains these behaviors.

What could I do ?

Comment: Have you tried to update the vendors with `php composer.phar update`? Anyway I think you should fix this security problem first. `::1` is the IPv6 address of localhost, so it seems that the request comes from your server.

Comment: please log in before editing your question (an edit was submitted by an anonymous user).